# Applying summations to inequalities

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing

I need to prove $$\sum_{k=2}^{n}f'(k) ≤ f(n) − f(1) ≤
\sum_{k}^{n-1}f'(k)$$
from
$$f'(k + 1) ≤ f(k + 1) − f(k) ≤ f'(k)$$.

where $k$ is positive.

Is it mathematically correct to apply summation to the inequality so:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f'(k + 1) ≤ \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k + 1) − f(k) ≤ \sum_{k=1}^{n}f'(k)$$

Comment: Yeah if it holds for all $k$  where the summation is taking place

Comment: Yes. If a<b and c<d you can deduce that a+c<b+d. Yours is just a more complex form of this. Proof: By definition, a<b if and only if there exists t>0 such that a+t=b. Take it from there...